# Can I set different database directories in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

In db2 we can create databases on different directories through `db2 list db directory`. Can we also do that on MongoDB?

I am aware of the `dbPath` in the config file. But do all databases created have to be stored there?

Answer (score 1):

All databases for a MongoDB server are created within the configured [`storage.dbPath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) directory.

You can't directly specify directory paths for new databases via an end user command, however you can enable the [`storage.directoryPerDB`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.directoryPerDB) option in your `mongod` config to use a separate subdirectory for each database. The subdirectory name used is determined by the storage engine, but the default storage engines (WiredTiger in MongoDB 3.2+, MMAPv1 in earlier versions) currently base this on the database name. Since database names use UTF8, any special characters that might be problematic will be encoded when mapped to a subdirectory name.

With a `directoryPerDB`  configuration you can also mount or symlink subdirectories to different volumes in your filesystem (assuming the `dbPath` isn't in use when you change existing mount points). This can be useful if you want to separate I/O for different databases. Note: if you end up managing databases on different volumes this may also affect your backup strategy. For example, filesystem-level backups require a consistent backup of the full `dbPath` — you cannot independently backup database subdirectories in a MongoDB deployment.

An important caveat noted in the documentation:

> To change the `directoryPerDB` option for existing deployments, you must restart  `mongod` instances with the new `directoryPerDB` value **and** a new data directory (`dbPath`), and then repopulate the data.

The `directoryPerDB` config option can vary per member in a replica set, which can be useful for migration between different `dbPath` layouts without downtime.